# Adding a form to the timeline object in sencha touch

Tags: sencha-touch

I have taken the form example from Sencha Touch API

```
    var form = new Ext.form.FormPanel({
    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'textfield',
            name : 'first',
            label: 'First name'
        },
        {
            xtype: 'textfield',
            name : 'last',
            label: 'Last name'
        },
        {
            xtype: 'numberfield',
            name : 'age',
            label: 'Age'
        },
        {
            xtype: 'urlfield',
            name : 'url',
            label: 'Website'
        }
    ]
});
```

and I have created a timeline object using

```
timeline = new Ext.Component({
        title: 'Loan Details',
        cls: 'timeline',
        scroll: 'vertical',
        tpl: ['<div></div>']
});
```

and then added the timeline to the panel as:

```
panel = new Ext.TabPanel({
        fullscreen: true,
        cardSwitchAnimation: 'slide',
        ui: 'light',
        items: [timeline]
    });
```

How can I add the form object to the timeline? Like how I can show that on it? Where I should add it?

Thanks for the response in advance.

Comment: I am trying to put a form on the timeline with a textbox and a submit button, when submit button gets clicked, I want the JSONP request to change the parameters and get new content, thanks to Ilija139 in another question, I know how to change the params of jsonp request but struggling to attach a form element to the timeline component in GeoTweets app: http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/touch/getting-started.html#DetailedSteps

Comment: As I said Ext.Component is only for showing static data, you must use Ext.Panel to have a form element attach to it. Also you can dock the FormPanel like this `var panel = new Ext.TabPanel({
            fullscreen: true,
            cardSwitchAnimation: 'slide',
            items: [map, timeline],
            dockedItems: [form]
        });` and have `dock: 'top'` property in the form object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are trying to do. Are you trying to have some kind of continuous carousel where you will put the FormPanel?
If so you should extend the Ext.Panel to make that timeline object and then as item use the xtype:'fieldset' and have the form items there.

For example:

```
App.views.Timeline = Ext.extend(Ext.Panel, {
initComponent: function() {
  Ext.apply(this, {
        title: 'Loan Details',
        cls: 'timeline',
        scroll: 'vertical',
        items:[
        {
            xtype: 'fieldset',
            defaults: {
            labelAlign: 'left',
            labelWidth: 'auto',
            }
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    name : 'first',
                    label: 'First name'
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    name : 'last',
                    label: 'Last name'
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'numberfield',
                    name : 'age',
                    label: 'Age'
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'urlfield',
                    name : 'url',
                    label: 'Website'
                }
            ]
            }
        ]
});
}});
```

the Ext.Component is for showing data through the data property. The data is display according to the template you provide i.e. the tpl property but you need to specify the property of the objects you want to show. For example `tpl:<div>{text}</div>` and `data:[{text:'Example'}]`